# SoapClient: Add NS to XML node

Tags: php, soap, xml-namespaces

I have a complicated xml I need to send over SoapClient.

I am trying to do it the "correct" way by sending an array of params with the request.

Here is an example of my current array:

```
$params = array("TestRequest" => array("NodeOne" => "Value1", "NodeTwo" => "Value2"));
```

It makes an xml like this:

```
<TestRequest>
   <NodeOne>Value1</NodeOne>
   <NodeTwo>Value2</NodeTwo>
</TestRequest>
```

However, I need to add the NS to the "TestRequest" Part.  It needs to look like this:

```
<ord:TestRequest>
   <NodeOne>Value1</NodeOne>
   <NodeTwo>Value2</NodeTwo>
</ord:TestRequest>
```

I have pulled my hair out trying everything I could think of, searched google and stack to no avail.  And yes, I have tried in the array typing, "ord:TestRequest".

If anyone is a SoapClient guru in PHP and could help, I will be forever thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after much headache... The easiest way to accomplish this is not the way I would prefer.

I ended up manually writing an XML like so:

```
$xml = '<ord:TestRequest>
   <NodeOne>Value1</NodeOne>
   <NodeTwo>Value2</NodeTwo>
</ord:TestRequest>';
```

PHP:

```
 $dom =new DOMDocument('1.0');
try {
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    $request = $dom->saveXML();
    $this->xml = $request;
    return true;
} catch (DOMException $e) {
    $this->xml = $xml;
    $this->errors++;
    $this->error_msg = 'Error generating XML :' . $e;
        }
```

My XML was structured just like it should to make a SoapRequest, then I used the SoapClient __doRequest() method.

Important, when you go this route you can't use your wsdl to auto-generate the xml as you already did it, so make sure in your soap connection and request your wsdl is null.

Comment: Important note: I left out the full xml and if you are using this for reference to the same issue, please visit SoapClient::__doRequest() at php.net to learn how to build the whole class